# Why is my List<string> not returning from MVC Controller from $ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create bespoke lists in my cshtml file using an ajax call

```
.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "@Url.Action("getValidationLists")",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {                
            var list = result.list;
            $.each(list, function (index, value) {
                alert(value);
            });
        }
    });
```

The Controller then collects the data puts it in a List and returns it to my cshtml file using json format. the controller method is below

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult getValidationLists()
{
    List<List<String>> validList = new List<List<String>>();
    List<UIReferenceData> results = AddErrorsToModelState<List<UIReferenceData>>(_StaticDataServiceAgent.GetAllAssetTypes());
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        List<String> resultList = new List<String>();
        string id = results[i].ID.ToString();
        string name = results[i].Name;
        resultList.Add(id);
        resultList.Add(name);
        validList.Add(resultList);
    }
    return Json(new
    {
        validList = validList
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I've tried several different versions but the returning code never gets as far as the alert(value); code.
What am i missing?

Comment: Can you debug the controller method? Can you intercept the call?

Comment: Yes, as far as the return and the List<string> validList has the correct data

Comment: Have you verified you are hitting your controller method and that it is not throwing a 500? If you are getting data back but you are not making it to the $.each it may be that you need to parse the result first: var list = JSON.parse(result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON response you are returning from your action method looks like this

```
{
    "validList": [      
        ["1", "SomeText"],
        ["2", "SomeText"],
        ["3", " SomeText"]
    ]
}
```

Your response has a `validList` property which is an array and each item in an array is again another array with 2 items.

This should work

```
 success: function (result) {           
     $.each(result.validList, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value[0]);
       console.log(value[1]);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The property name is inconsistent with what you are returning from your action:

```
var list = result.list;
```

Should be:

```
var list = result.validList;
```

However you are returning a `List<List<String>>` rather than a `List<String>` too.

I think you need to address both of the above in order to fix.